# Regex (java) - extracting from payload

Tags: java, regex

`000klkj1-041-3501-0071-00000kjhh05601    56hj1 66553  78 546623`

payload follows same structure every time and I'm trying to find numerical values that reside after 3 spaces (or 3 whitespaces?) (in this case "78"). the number(s) (1 or 2 numbers at most) will always be after 3 spaces; this is the only commonality between multiple payloads. other than \d+, I have nothing so far.  any/all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see you explaining structure. three numbers, four letters, one number, dash? eight alphanumerics, dash? three numbers, five alphanumerics? Hint: explicitly write out the structure, and we'll be much better able to help, although you might already answer your own question during that exercise.

Comment: If you are not familiar with regular expressions, you may want to look into `indexOf`.

Comment: In what you've shown here, 78 appears after two spaces, not three. Are you sure you have your requirements right?

Comment: I apologize, I didn't explain it very well.  The payload(s) are gibberish.  I'm trying to pull out the first two numbers (in some cases, in a single number) that occur after the 3rd space. the alphanumeric characters and strings proceeding the 3rd space vary in length with each payload.  does that help at all? again, sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really hard to understand your question but if you want to get the numbers after 3 spaces you can use this regex:

```
^(?:\S*\s+){3}(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hD3kO3/2)**

[image]

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [50-52] `78`
MATCH 2
1.  [114-116]   `78`
```

Comment: Thank you Fede (any others).  This worked and will help me phrase future questions in a more intuitive manner.

Answer (score 0):

If your input line consists of fields separated by groups of one or more whitespaces, it might be easiest to use `split` instead of a regex:

```
String[] fields = inputString.split("\\s+");
```

Now `fields[0]` is the first field, `fields[1]` is the second, etc., so `fields[3]` should give you what you want.